# How use cap_dac_override from libcap

Tags: linux

I'm trying to test cap_dac_override. I've written a simple hello world. I've compiled the program and I've removed all the permissions from the executable.

At this moment I'm not able to execute my program by running ./hello which is correct. Now I would like to apply a capability so that the program can still be executed even though the user has no execute permission.

May I ask how set up cap_dac_override so that I can still execute the program, or am i using cap_dac_override completely wrong?

```
setcap cap_dac_override=ep hello
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing capabilities and permissions.

The *file mode bits* or *permissions* describe **what can be done with a file**. When you removed all permissions from a file you instructed the OS that you don't want anyone to read from it, write to it or execute it.

File capabilities on the other hand describe **what a file can do** or to be exact, what a process originating from that program file can do, what it otherwise wouldn't be able to do.

With `setcap cap_dac_override=ep hello` you allowed the program `hello` to override the usual permission checks when it runs. But that doesn't change that the usual permission checks are applied when trying to execute `hello`.

Comment: Hi Cg909, would you happen to know of an example process I can use with cap_dac_override so I can understand it better.

Comment: @Master Sorry, I don't know an example program for cap_dac_override. It's a very powerful and dangerous capability as it allows the program to read, modify, delete and create **any** file regardless of ownership or permissions. Also it allows the program to execute any file that has at least one execute bit set. To understand it better try to extend your hello world program to read and/or write to some file and then change the permissions of this file so that `hello` shouldn't have access to it.

Comment: The `beep` program, which is used to make a sound through the pc speaker, is an example that can use the cap_dac_override capability. To function, the beep program needs access to `/dev/console`. Making the beep program setuid would enable access, but would also grant it a lot of other privileges it really doesn't need. As an alternative, by granting the beep program cap_dac_override, you can restrict the special powers to opening files (and not e.g. writing raw sockets).